# What could cause the spike in the Venezuelan unofficial currency exchange?

Tags: inflation, exchange-rates, black-market

In November last year the unofficial currency exchange rate in Venezuela skyrocketed. It was only one month later that the government was able to slow the increase rate to “normal” values. The government alleged that some mafias where smuggling the Venezuelan money out of the country across the border, which doesn’t even make sense, since the biggest banknote in Venezuela was worth only about 5 cents of a dollar at most in the unofficial currency exchange market.

This is the unofficial exchange rate tracked by a third party web site:

[image]